# J. T. B. Beard's algorithm to catch `perfect polynomials`

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

For any monic polynomial $P$ with coefficients in a finite field of order $q$, we put

$$
\sigma(P) = \sum_{d \mid P, d \text{ monic}} d.
$$

Observe that $P$ and $\sigma(P)$ have the same degree.

EDIT. $A$ means the full ring of polynomials in one variable $t$ over the finite field with $q$ elements.

Since there are a finite number of polynomials of a given degree in $A$ 
the sequence
$$
P, \sigma(P), \sigma(\sigma(P)), \ldots
$$
must contain two equal terms.

The following algorithm (of J. T. B. Beard)
seems to catch monic polynomials $P \in A$ with $\sigma(P)=P$
when $q$ is a prime number.

(i)
Take $R=R_0$ a `well chosen`  polynomial in $A.$

(ii)
If $R=\sigma(R)$ STOP and output $R.$

(ii)
 if $R \neq \sigma(R)$ then replace $R$ by
$$
lcm(R,\sigma(R))
$$
and come back to (ii)

Question: Take $q=2.$ For which polynomials $R_0$ l'algorithm stops after a finite number of steps. 
Assume that a polynomial $P \in A$ satisfies $P=\sigma(P).$ There exists a polynomial $R_0 \neq P$
and $R_0 \neq P(t+1),$
such that by taking $R=R_0$ in (i) the algorithm stops after a finite number of steps and outputs $P$?

Example: With $R_0=t$ we catch  $P=t(t+1)$ that satisfies $P=\sigma(P).$
More involved examples can be obtained with a small computer program;
(or by hand depending on taste...).

EDIT1: I tried recently to catch J. T. B. Beard himself to ask for this algorithm (and many other related questions in my mind...)
but I got only some (nice) comments from people close to him in his last known position in the usa.
No more news about him known by myself.

Comment: Is $A$ the set of monic polynomials of a fixed degree, or?!

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure if I understand you right. But given the definition, since $P | P$, then is what you are looking equivalent to $P$ such that $\sum_{d|P, d\neq p} d = 0$? Calling it "perfect" (even if it is established usage) feels a bit misleading to me. 

Comment: Have you done any experiments with $q=2$ to see for which polynomials the procedure seems to terminate?

Comment: @Igor: I was unable to write in MO's latex:  $A=\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ in the post. Hope now works here 
in this comment !!!
(does not compiled correctly for me while writing the post). 
Anyway, $A$ means the full ring of polynomials with coefficients in a finite field.



Comment: @Willie: Perhaps `multiperfect` is better. The idea is: `multiperfect` over the integers means loosely:
$n$ divides $\sigma(n)$, so the notion can be also defined in $A$. But then you are forced to take $P=\sigma(P)$
since $P$ divides $\sigma(P)$ implies $P=\sigma(P)$ in $A.$
While over the integers you can take $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ whatever you want  (e.g. $=2$: define perfects,
 $=3$ define $3$-multiperfect numbers, $=8$: etc, etc.)
over $A$ there is just one choice; (for the definition above of $\sigma$ of course).



Comment: @Gerry: Initial element seems to behave `randomly'; but I have done
only very few checks.


Comment: Maybe you should do a few more checks, systematic checks, all polynomials up to some particular degree, maybe you'll see a pattern, or maybe we will, if you report your results. 

Comment: @Willie, Luis: A more standard definition of $\sigma(P)$ (e.g. in Rosen Number Theory in Function Fields) is the sum of $\lvert d\rvert$ over monic d dividing P, which may explain the confusion.